# align numbering works strange

Tags: numbering, align

My understanding is that `align` numbering works the same as `equation`. But in my case, it works very strangely. See my codes as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a &= a \\ \label{a}
b &= b    \label{b}
\end{align}

\Equation eqref{a} is different from equation \eqref{b}.
\end{document}
```

And I always get the first equation in the main text very strange (with two question marks). See my result:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The warning I get seems to explain the problem: Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'a' will be lost. \end{align}

Comment: Put `\label{a}` _before_ \\.

Comment: the problem has already been solved, but here's another way to think about it:  a label *must* be on the same line as the equation it's numbering.  `\\ ` starts a new line, so putting a label *after* that may result in two labels being on the same line, and in such a case, only the last label will be recognized or honored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\label{a}` must be written before `\\`.

And there was a `\Equation` error, most probably a typo.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a &= a  \label{a} \\
b &= b    \label{b}
\end{align}

Equation \eqref{a} is different from equation \eqref{b}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you so much! My problem is solved!

Comment: @ppp If this answer solved your issue, click the little checkmark (making it green) to mark this as 'accepted' -- this is the idiomatic way to say 'thanks' on this site :)